# How to use local value globally? Lua

Tags: lua

Well, i was trying this for 3 days, nothing found on web.

What i am doing is this:

```
stringValue = ""

function()
    stringValue = "Test"
end
```

And then i am trying to get the value in another function by this:

```
function()
    print(stringValue);
end
```

And it returns nothing, sometimes NIL sometimes blank.

I was thinking if someone could help me? I'm sorry if its already asked ... If it was, kindly give me link i am new here.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. There are no local variables in your code, either.  So it's hard to understand what you meant by **How to use local value globally?** Learn [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Actually i aint making program, i am doing something else. In my case, i call functions by events. Its something else i cant describe.

Comment: @YuHao why do you say it does not compile? works fine for me. but of course does nothing, because it defines an anonymous function that's not assigned or called anywhere, so it gets garbage collected. but you're right, no locals anywhere :D

Comment: i suspect you're calling these two functions in different parts/events/whatever, and maybe the application has different _ENVs for these? or maybe, `stringValue` is really a local (and you just forgot to add that in your examplecode), and not upvalue to both of these functions, because e.g. they're defined in different closures

Comment: @nonchip http://ideone.com/WhOWtZ doesn't compile.

Comment: @YuHao ok, sorry, my fault, I had just pasted it in my IDE's Lua REPL to test it and forgot about the syntax handling for "standalone rvalues". good to know the REPL messes with the syntax before executing...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work, you have to invoke the function

```
stringValue = ""

function a()
    stringValue = "Test"
end

function b()
    print(stringValue);
end

a()
b()
```

Answer (score 0):

[Global variables are bad](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?GlobalVariablesAreBad) (in [many](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil) cases)!

They increase coupling and ruin any design if used carelessly.

Just don't do it.

Apart from that, you haven't called your first function, if you did, you'd get the needed value.